# Android EditText Hint with Drawable Centered

Tags: android, xml

[image]

- I apologize for not posting actual image. It appears I do not have the rep to do so at this time.

I would like to create an edit text similar to search in the image above.
I previously attempted to create this using an edit text with a drawable left, but I couldn't quite center the image with the text using padding and drawablePadding.

Currently I have this in my xml layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/countryCodeSearch"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:background="@color/tiara"
            android:hint="@string/search"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mag_glass"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="90dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="90dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone point me in a better direction?? I have looked at a few other examples of this here on Stack Overflow, but couldn't find any where the textview hint and drawable needed to be centered.

Thanks All!

Comment: Please post an image of the way the XML layout is currently using Imgur.com and then put the link here.

Comment: Also can you explain which of the following you are trying to achieve? 
1. Center everything in the relative layout.
2. Center the EditText above the ImageView.
3. Center the ImageView below the EditText.
4. Other, please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your class:

```
EditText searchEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.searchEditText);

    Drawable img;
    Resources res = getResources();
    img = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.search_icon);
    img.setBounds(0, 0, 40, 40);
    searchEditText.setCompoundDrawables(img, null, null, null);
    searchEditText.setCompoundDrawablePadding(40);
    searchEditText.setPadding(40,0,0,0);
```

You have to change `setBounds`, `setCompoundDrawablePadding` and `setPadding` to yours values.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't think of setting the bounds of the image. This allowed me to give the image the needed top and bottom margins while also allowing me to center the image next to the edittext's hint.